# See the SQL query that gets executed when saving entry

Tags: plugin-development, entries, mysql

I'm creating a pretty specific entry with some fields. And I want to create the from a third party app. For that, I'd like to see the SQL query that get executed.

I've tried it with events, `entries.onBeforeSaveEntry`and `content.saveContent` but I cannot get the query itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you add the [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) setting to your config, you should then be able to view the Javascript Console in your browser to see the SQL Queries being run.

In particular you're looking for the `Profiling Summary Report`.

Also, you can view the Craft Logs at `/admin/utils/logs`, when you are logged into the Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Steve's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/19610/57), if you install [xDebug](https://xdebug.org), you can put a breakpoint in `craft/app/EntriesService()->saveEntry()` and step through/into and watch the SQL query be built and executed.